# Class vector has no member

Tags: c++, vector, member

I'm collecting names and test scores to populate a vector. Both the function and main method can't recognize the struct's members. How can I get it to see the members? Or is there a better way to populate a vector of structs with user input using a function?

I've searched other similar posts, but it seems like it's just a simple code error I missed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

const int classSize = 1;

struct StudentType {
    string studentFName;
    string studentLName;
    int testScore;
    char grade;
};

vector<StudentType> collectStudentData(vector<StudentType> students[classSize]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < classSize; i++) {
        cout << "Student " << i << "'s name and test score" << endl;
        cin >> students[i].studentFName >> students[i].studentLName >> students[i].testScore;
    }
    return students[classSize];
};

int main() {
    vector<StudentType> students[classSize] = {};
    students[classSize] = collectStudentData(students);
    cout << students[1].studentFName << students[1].studentLName << students[1].studentFName;
};
```

'studentFName': is not a member of 'std::vector>'

Comment: Change `vector<StudentType> students[classSize] = {};` to `vector<StudentType> students;` (and again in the declaration of `collectStudentData`).

Comment: @PaulSanders several other changes are necessary as well

Comment: You'd better use vector of vectors instead array of vectors

Comment: @NutCracker I think they only want a single vector but are confused about the language syntax

Comment: @MM Yes, the OP needs to at least allocate space in the vector before reading into it.

Comment: Oh, could be. I was thinking they wanted to have students from all classes but if I look closer it seems that's not the case. Thx

Comment: `students[classSize] = ...` would also be an out of bounds error

Comment: Why do you need an array or vector of vectors?

Comment: Oh, I only wanted one vector for a single class of students. Thanks for clearing this up

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print vector's data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800741/how-to-print-vectors-data). There are also [No operator “=” matches these operands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444377/no-operator-matches-these-operands/30444397) and [C++ vector::begin not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51729585/c-vectorbegin-not-working/51729625) as newer potential duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line creates an *array of vectors*:

```
vector<StudentType> students[classSize] = {};
```

What you want is this a single vector:

```
vector<StudentType> students;
```

Where that gets initialized to a zero-length array.

When it comes to adding data you don't need to return from the other method, you can pass in a reference and add to it:

```
void collectStudentData(vector<StudentType>& students) {
  for (int i = 0; i < classSize; i++) {
    // Read in one at a time
    StudentType  student;
    cout << "Student " << i << "'s name and test score" << endl;
    cin >> student.studentFName >> student.studentLName >> student.testScore;

    // Add to the array
    students.push_back(student);
  }
}
```

Ideally `classSize` is either passed in as an argument, or you just type a blank line to end input. Using a global variable is really messy and should be *strongly discouraged*.

Comment: Thank you! hopefully this fixes my issues

Answer (score 2):

```
vector<StudentType> students[classSize]
```

Is one issue. You are not declaring a function that takes a vector, you are declaring a function that takes an array of vectors.

Secondly, if you only applied that change you would be passing an empty vector, you can initialize vector to be a particular size by passing in the size to the constructor.

Furthermore, it seems that you would benefit from passing the students vector by reference

```
vector<StudentType>& students
```

instead, the & creates a reference. Right now your code is copying the vector when it is passed into the function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

const int classSize = 1;

struct StudentType {
    string studentFName;
    string studentLName;
    int testScore;
    char grade;
};

void collectStudentData(vector<StudentType>& students) {
    for (int i = 0; i < classSize; i++) {
        cout << "Student " << i << "'s name and test score" << endl;
        cin >> students[i].studentFName >> students[i].studentLName >> students[i].testScore;
    }
    return students;
};

int main() {
    vector<StudentType> students{classSize};
    collectStudentData(students);
    cout << students[0].studentFName << students[0].studentLName << students[0].studentFName;
};
```

If you wanted to improve the code further, you would use an iterator in the for loop instead, and preferably you wouldn't need to construct the vector in main, and pass it into a function to mutate it. You could just construct it and return it from the function.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to accept the vector by reference and also return it by value. Probably the function should take no arguments and just return a vector

Comment: Also you read out of bounds on the last line (vector indices start at 0)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can't believe I thought it started at 1. I've done this before lol